# Create a custom mapping method to map a property using Riok.Mapperly

Tags: c#, mapper, mapperly

Using Riok.Mapperly and C#, I need to map a property of type string that contains values like this `"1_2_4_8"` and map it to a `List<int>`.
I know I can add a method to the mapping class for Mapperly to pick, like so:

```
[Mapper]
public static partial class CountryMapper
{
    public static partial M.Country ToBoCountry(this EF.Country country);
    private static List<int> SplitUnderscore(string? str)
    {
        return str is null ? [] : [.. str.Split('_').Where(x => 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(int.Parse)];
    }
}
```

This way if an other property in the County class has a string that has the values like this `"1|2|4|8"`, I cannot create another method like this:

```
private static List<int> SplitPipe(string? str)
{
    return str is null ? [] : [.. str.Split('|').Where(x => 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(int.Parse)];
}
```

It will just pick the first it finds.

Is there a way to instruct mapperly what method to use to map a specific property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible with Mapperly. What you need is [#783](https://github.com/riok/mapperly/issues/783). A PR implementing this is open and will probably be merged in a few weeks. You can subscribe to the issue to get updates as they arrive.